# "plot.new has not been called yet" error in R

Tags: r

```
plot(y = spd$Frequency, x = spd$Date, xlab = "Date", ylab = "Frequency of Usage", main = "Platform Usage over time", type = 'l')
abline(lm(Frequency ~ Date, data = spd)
```

I have a time-series data frame called spd, and I am trying to plot Frequency column against Date column, and then draw a linear regression line to display the trend. It is a simple problem, but no matter what I do, I keep getting the 'plot.new has not been called yet' error.

I believe that the error occurs if you have not plotted anything yet, yet you call abline() which results in an error. But above, I clearly call plot() already and it works fine. Appreciate all help :)

Comment: You code is missing a closing parenthesis.